# Calculate number of months away from today's date

Tags: vba

I'm trying to subtract a user given date from today's date and return a number that represents the number of months away from today's date. Here is the code I have, it keeps returning 0 though.

```
Public Function QProfile(Arg1 As Date)
    Dim Tdate As Date
    Dim Idate As Date
    Dim Rdate As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim N As Integer
    Tdate = Today()
    Idate = Arg1
    Rdate = Today() - Arg1
    Result = 7
    N = 30
    If Rdate <= N Then
        Result = 1
    End If
    If Rdate >= N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 2 Then
        Result = 2
    End If
    If Rdate >= 2 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 3 Then
        Result = 3
    End If
    If Rdate >= 3 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 4 Then
        Result = 4
    End If
    If Rdate >= 4 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 5 Then
        Result = 5
    End If
    If Rdate >= 5 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 6 Then
        Result = 6
    End If
    If Rdate >= 6 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 7 Then
        Result = 7
    End If
    If Rdate >= 7 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 8 Then
        Result = 8
    End If
    If Rdate >= 8 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 9 Then
        Result = 9
    End If
    If Rdate >= 9 * N + 1 And Rdate <= N * 10 Then
        Result = 10
    End If
    If Rdate >= 11 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 365 Then
        Result = 12
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 1 And Rdate <= N + 365 Then
        Result = 13
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 1 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 2 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 14
    End If
     If Rdate >= 365 + 2 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 3 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 15
    End If
     If Rdate >= 365 + 3 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 4 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 16
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 4 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 5 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 17
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 5 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 6 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 18
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 6 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 7 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 19
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 7 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 8 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 20
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 8 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 9 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 21
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 9 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 10 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 22
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 10 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 11 * N + 365 Then
        Result = 23
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 + 11 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 24
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 1 And Rdate <= 1 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 25
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 1 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 2 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 26
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 2 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 3 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 27
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 3 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 4 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 28
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 4 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 5 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 29
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 5 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 6 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 30
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 6 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 7 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 31
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 7 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 8 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 32
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 8 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 9 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 33
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 9 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 10 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 34
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 10 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 11 * N + 2 * 365 Then
        Result = 35
    End If
    If Rdate >= 365 * 2 + 11 * N + 1 And Rdate <= 3 * 365 Then
        Result = 36
    End If
    If Rdate > 3 * 365 + 1 Then
        Result = 37
    End If
    QProfile = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Why not just the formula: `=INT((TODAY()-A1)/30)+1` which what you are attempting with your code.  or in vba `Result = INT((DATE-Arg1)/30)+1`

Comment: I clearly way over thought this lol

Comment: DateDiff("m", now, "2020-01-01")